Invalid pointer address after mmap (uio)
I am trying to use mmap to map a uio device for user-space usage.
This is what I use in my code:
map = mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}

fd is dev/uio0 device
In the address value, I use NULL, which, to the best of my knowledge lets the kernel find the right address according to the device opened.
It fails, and the map pointer value is 0xffffffff.
I hope you guys can help me figure out what's wrong with my implementation. I'd add more details if necessary.

edit:
This is how I open the UIO device:
    fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }

the error printed is mmap: No such device

Can you write a [mcve] that shows how you're obtaining fd and that you've checked it?  Thanks.  And are you sure it points to a file that can actually be mapped?

What does perror print? If you have it in your code, you should show us the output.

Are the length (MAP_SIZE) and offset (0) correct?

@TobySpeight I've added an example. I am sure because I generated the device tree. This code should eventually access an FPGA GP registers. The device is accessible via devmem, so I know it works.

@Gerhardh Yes, sorry. Added to the question.

@IanAbbott Yes.

How do you find DEVICE? How do you know it is the correct device file? Have you checked that the kernel driver is loaded? Have you checked that the driver gives you support for memory mapping?

@JeremyP It uses the generic-uio driver, the logic will be made in user-space.
I can access the device with devmem and read corrert values from an R/O register.
In addition, it appears on '/sys/class/uio' as a uio device (with the correct data from the device tree), and in /dev/ as the device.

There isn't a driver called "generic-uio". Which one do you really mean?

Note that the driver needs to make the struct uio_mem structure value compatible with mmap by rounding down the addr member to a PAGE_SIZE boundary, setting the offs member to the offset within the page, and setting the size member to cover all the pages that overlap the memory region.

Also, which kernel version are you using, because there have been changes to the way non-page-aligned memory regions are described to the UIO subsystem around kernel version 5.9 or so.

@IanAbbott I am using 4.9.x version, with 'uio' driver. (uio.c on buildroot)

It isn't necessary to include "edit" in your title when you edit a post; I removed it.  The SO interface shows edits and lets people see the full edit history if they want.

I can't work out how mmap in the uio driver in 4.9.x is supposed to work with non-page-aligned regions. struct uio_mem has no offs member, but uio extracts the offset from the addr member to get the value for the offset sysfs file. However, the mmap handler for the UIO_MEM_PHYS  memory type (function uio_mmap_physical) fails with your ENODEV error if the addr member is not page-aligned. You may need to work around it by either upgrading the kernel or by providing your own mmap handler in your struct uio_info.

@IanAbbott What I didn't mention on the question was that I can ask somebody to change the physical address of these FPGA registers.
Changing the address to a multiple of a page (let's say 0x1234000 instead of 0x1234500) have solved this issue and the UIO's implementation of 'mmap' worked fine.
Thanks for your help here.
